# @DiffIgnore and @ShallowReference causing weird behaviour in callbacks

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, javers

Just started using javers in place of envers and was stuck in associations(@OneToMany and @ManyToOne). 
To prevent javers from scanning and registering all association changes I applied @DiffIgnore on all @OneToMany associations and strangely when i get the entity in postpersist event of hibernate it @DiffIgnore annotated properties are ignored and I got lazy init exception when accessing those fields.

Here is my sample entity:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "property")
@ShallowReference
private List<PropertyImage> propertyImages = new ArrayList<>();
```

Property Images

```
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "property_id", referencedColumnName = "property_id", nullable = false)
private Property property;
```

Also I tried @ShallowReference annotation but again it fetches all associated entities and causes performance issue.

But when I change @FetchType.EAGER it works fine. Confused what's the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShallowReference desn't work with Lists, we have open issue for that, see https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/528

Comment: Since Javers 5.3.0, @ShallowReference works for Collections and Maps.